# itext issue: IE7 showing 404 sorry page title in the tab

Tags: internet-explorer-7, itext

I am trying to figure out why I'm getting this tab title in IE7. The tab says "We're sorry/(french equivalent)" which is basically our 404 not found page title. The pdf is generated fine and the response status is 200, why is it still redirecting to the 404?

The weird thing is its only happening to my machine, my coworker is also using IE7 and he doesn't see the "We're sorry...." tab title.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<title>` tags in your HTML head section? I've experienced in some cases that if I were to get a 404 (say by mistyping a URL) and then navigate to a page with no `<title>` tags, the title of the window / tab would remain the same as it was on the 404 page.

Try adding `<title>My Document</title>` to your page and see if this corrects the behavior.

Comment: There is no title tag and no html at all, the pdf is generated in the outputstream and post in the response. So IE is just opening a PDF. At first I thought there was something causing a 404 but I used httpfox in firefox and there was nothing. Just 200 status code.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I'm not sure. There's no HTTP header I've seen that would be an alternative to TITLE tags.